# Hide bar outline in bar chart?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

All the bars in my bar chart have black outlines:

[image]

How can I get rid of the outline or change their color?

---

The first 10 bars or so:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines = center,
        axis line style = {-},
        xlabel = $$,
        ylabel = $$,
        xmin = 0,
        xmax = 0.001,
        clip=false,
        xtick = {0, 0.001},
        xticklabels = {$0$, $0.001$},
        ymin = -0.6,
        ymax = 0.6,
        ytick = {0.6,0,0.6},
        yticklabels = {$0.6$,$0$,$0.6$},
        height = 10em,
        width = 30em,
      ]
      \addplot [
        ybar,
        fill=blue,
        bar width=0.000005,
      ]
      coordinates {
        (0,0.00928)
        (0.00002083333,0.23672)
        (0.00004166667,0.31467)
        (0.0000625,0.58179)
        (0.00008333333,0.46774)
        (0.0001041667,0.71017)
        (0.000125,0.45074)
        (0.0001458333,0.61990)
        (0.0001666667,0.30692)
        (0.0001875,0.41278)
        (0.0002083333,0.21576)
        (0.0002291667,0.31616)
        (0.00025,0.35751)
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: In red:`\addplot [
      red,
        ybar,
        fill=blue,
        bar width=1,
      ]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `draw=none`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines = center,
        axis line style = {-},
        xlabel = $$,
        ylabel = $$,
        xmin = 0,
        xmax = 0.001,
        clip=false,
        xtick = {0, 0.001},
        xticklabels = {$0$, $0.001$},
        ymin = -0.6,
        ymax = 0.6,
        ytick = {0.6,0,0.6},
        yticklabels = {$0.6$,$0$,$0.6$},
        height = 10em,
        width = 30em,
      ]
      \addplot [
        ybar,
        fill=blue,
        draw=none,
        bar width=0.000005,
      ]
      coordinates {
        (0,0.00928)
        (0.00002083333,0.23672)
        (0.00004166667,0.31467)
        (0.0000625,0.58179)
        (0.00008333333,0.46774)
        (0.0001041667,0.71017)
        (0.000125,0.45074)
        (0.0001458333,0.61990)
        (0.0001666667,0.30692)
        (0.0001875,0.41278)
        (0.0002083333,0.21576)
        (0.0002291667,0.31616)
        (0.00025,0.35751)
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This will also hide error bars. Is there a clean way to keep the errors while still removing the border from the bars?